# Blogdown GitHub Issues

Tags: r, github, blogdown

I have developed a blogdown site and I am ready to upload it to GitHub. I will be using netlify as well to display the site and I have my domain name ready to go. It is not finished because I want to be able to add things and understand that process while working further on it. I can not understand for the life of me how to upload this. I have tried the new/existing repo schemes. I have tried everything from every site. Do not just send some documentation script cause I have read all them.

Comment: What do you want to upload? I personally "deleted" `public` and just add everything to `/` but that may not be very desirable or standard practice. I don't know if you have tried [this](https://amber.rbind.io/2016/12/19/website/).

Comment: For the record, this was [cross-posted](https://yihui.org/en/2017/10/cross-posting/) at https://github.com/rstudio/blogdown/issues/471.